# Extracting the parts of string into array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, preg-match

I have a string that I need to explode and get the information.

**Sample string:**

```
"20' Container 1, 40' Open Container 1, 40-45' Closed Container 3"
```

First I am exploding the string by `,` and getting

```
"20' Container 1"
"40' Open Container 1"
"40-45' Closed Container 3"
```

Now I want to explode the already exploded array as well so that I get the result in below format

```
array[
    0 => [
        0 => "20'"
        1 => "Container"
        2 => "1"
        ]
    1 => [
        0 => "40'"
        1 => "Open Container"
        2 => "1"
        ]
    ]
```

The strings may vary but it is decided that the format will be same e.g. `length type number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop thru exploded string with comma delimiter, then push each matches base on `length type number` to result array

```
$string = "20' Container 1, 40' Open Container 1, 40-45' Closed Container 3";

$result = [];
$pattern = '/([\d-]*\')\s(.*)\s(\d+)/';
foreach (explode(', ', $string) as $value) {
    preg_match($pattern, $value, $matches); // Match length, type, number
    $result[] = array_slice($matches, 1);   // Slice with offset 1
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: This gives me 4 indexes of array in 2nd iteration. I want 3 indexes of each array as my result set

Comment: What will be the exact pattern here in this case?

Comment: You the life saver :p

Comment: I edited the pattern to match with lengths that has range

Answer (score 1):

You can simply explode one more time to get required array,

```
$str = "20' Container 1, 40' Open Container 1, 40-45' Closed Container 3";
$result = array();
$temp= explode(", ",$str);
array_walk($temp, function($item, $key) use(&$result) {
    $result[$key] = explode(" ", $item);
});
print_r($result);
```

Here is working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0c2c83a31285a3fce96261af39e3b41f15b332e8).

Comment: I want 3 indexes of each array. 2nd iteration gives me 4 indexes

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go:

```
$str = "20' Container 1, 40' Open Container 1, 40-45' Closed Container 3";
preg_match_all("/(\d+(?:-\d+)?')\s+([a-z\s]+)\s(\d+)(?:, )?/i", $str, $match);
for($i = 0; $i <3; $i++) {
    $final[] = array_slice(array_column($match, $i), 1);
}
print_r($final);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20'
            [1] => Container
            [2] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40'
            [1] => Open Container
            [2] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40-45'
            [1] => Closed Container
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

**Regex:**

```
/               : regex delimiter
  (             : start group 1
    \d+         : 1 or more digits
    (?:-\d+)?   : non capture group, a dash followed by digits, optional
    '           : 'single quote
  )             : end group 1
  \s+           : 1 or more spaces
  (             : start group 2
    [a-z\s]+    : 1 or more alphabetic or space
  )             : end group 2
  \s+           : 1 or more spaces
  (             : start group 3
    \d+         : 1 or more digits
  )             : end group 3
  (?:, )?       : non capture group, a comma followed by space, optional
/i              : regex delimiter, case insensitive
```